# Python - SqlAlchemy foreign key issues

Tags: python, flask, sqlalchemy

So, I have been getting a lot of errors with SQLAlchemy from Flask and so far nothing I have found online has fixed it, only caused further errors to appear. My current model code is here:

```py
class User(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = "users"
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    nickname = db.Column(db.String(64), index=True, unique=True)
    email = db.Column(db.String(120), unique=True, nullable=False)
    posts = db.relationship('Post', back_populates='author', lazy='dynamic',
                            primaryjoin='User.id == Post.user_id')
    created_at = db.Column(db.DateTime, default=datetime.datetime.utcnow())

    @property
    def is_authenticated(self):
        return True

    @property
    def is_active(self):
        return True

    @property
    def is_anonymous(self):
        return False

    def get_id(self):
        return str(self.id)

    def __repr__(self):
        return "<User %r>" % (self.nickname)

class Post(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'post'
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    body = db.Column(db.String(140))
    timestamp = db.Column(db.DateTime)
    user_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('user.id'))

    def __repr__(self):
        return '<Post %r>' % (self.body)
```

My current error with this code is:

```
sqlalchemy.exc.NoReferencedTableError: Foreign key associated with column 'post.user_id' could not find table 'user' with which to generate a foreign key to target column 'id'
```

I am at a complete loss as to what I'm doing wrong and why it is that no other solution has worked for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`user.id` needs to be `users.id` in your `Post` model:

```
user_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('users.id'))
```

Comment: Or rather, perhaps the table name should be in singular ,,,